# Top level await gives error in build but works on dev

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, async-await, vite

My code works when ran `npm run dev` but when I build it it gives this error. According to the docs I need target set to ES2017 or higher in tsconfig.json but I am using ESNEXT which I believe is compatible

error
[image: error]

tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "lib": ["DOM", "DOM.Iterable", "ESNext"],
    "allowJs": false,
    "skipLibCheck": false,
    "esModuleInterop": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "include": ["./src"]
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because I was using vite in the question, vite.config.ts is what I should have been looking to edit instead of tsconfig.json

here is the fix to it
vite.config.ts

```
export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    minify: 'esbuild',
    target: "esnext"
  }
})
```

Comment: Can you share your whole config? I have the same problem with VitePluginNode, but adding the build options did not help

Comment: As far as I understand this just disables transpilation and assumes the browser supports every possible feature. If that is correct, this is NOT THE SOLUTION to make top-level-await work.

Comment: For me. This is still not helping. :(